# nextjs 13 accessing js script in node_modules from layout

Tags: next.js13

I just installing a package on my nextjs 13. And its require me to include package.min.js that located on /node_modules/package/dist/package.min.js before the end of body tag.

So, on my layout.tsx i call like this

```
...
return(
<html
      lang="en"
      style={{ colorScheme: 'light' }}
    >
<body className={roboto.className} >
        {children}
<script src="../../node_modules/package/dist/package.min.js"></script>
</body >

    </html >
)
```

but it doesn't work

here is my project structure

```
/root
  |-node_modules
  |-src
     |-app
        |-layout.tsx
```